# Android - can vector drawables store GIF files/animated images?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-image, android-vectordrawable

I have made a custom keyboard that allows users to send GIFs/Images.

Currently, whenever the user taps on a `ImageView`, the following code runs. It checks whether the drawable inside the `ImageView` is animated (i.e - the image is a `GifDrawable`) and if not, it casts it to a `BitmapDrawable`. `context.contentComitter.commit()` is responsible for turning the casted drawables into files that can be read by other apps.

```
        if(holder.imageView.drawable is GifDrawable) {
            context.contentCommitter.commitGifDrawable(holder.imageView.drawable, fileName)
        } else {
            context.contentCommitter.commitBitmapDrawable(holder.imageView.drawable as BitmapDrawable, fileName)
        }
```

The problem is - I'm getting the following crash for certain images on Samsung Galaxy S9s only:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException
>   android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

The solution seems to be simple - just perform another check for whether `holder.imageView.drawable` is a `VectorDrawable`, and if so, extract the `Bitmap` and write it to a file.

However, the problem is that the `VectorDrawable` source seems to be a GIF file, instead of a static image. This is confusing because the methods in the `VectorDrawable` documentation indicate that it is only used to store static images.

Is it possible for a `VectorDrawable` to contain animated images (i.e - GIFs), or do `VectorDrawable`s only contain static images?

Here is the image database: https://github.com/vedantroy/Image-Database

Comment: You aren't reading that right.  A VectorDrawable is neither a GIF nor a Bitmap.  You code there assumes that anything that isn't a gif is a bitmap.  You seem to have a 3rd case-  a vector.  And you need to code in support for that 3rd case.  A vector drawable, btw, doesn't hold static images.  They hold instructions on how to draw an image at runtime that scales.  Its explicitly not a static image because those scale poorly.

Comment: I understand that an image can be neither a GIF or a Bitmap. However, I'm confused, because all the SO posts I've read indicate that it is possible to get **a** Bitmap from a `VectorDrawable`, thus indicating a `VectorDrawable` only holds non-animated images. This confuses me, because according to my crash reports, the source of the `VectorDrawable` is a GIF.

Comment: According to what you posted, it was trying to cast it to a BitmapDrawable.  Which occurs in your else, so its not saying its a GIF.  You cannot directly get a Bitmap from a VectorDrawable, because it isn't stored that way.  You can draw it to a Canvas backed by a Bitmap and then use that.

Comment: That's what I thought - but the source of the image was https://github.com/vedantroy/Image-Database/blob/master/Curated/Angry/angrypout.gif, which is definitely a GIF.

Comment: I'd look at some weirdness in whatever image library you're using to load it.  Gifs aren't even natively supported by Android, so you're using some 3rd party library in there.  It must be loading it into a vector for some reason.